# How were the ramps for the Zhurong rover stowed on the lander for flight?

Tags: mechanisms, zhurong

This picture shows a lander-eye-view of the ramps.

[image]

This rendering shows a side view.

[image]

How did the ramp deployment mechanism work, and what did the ramps look like while stowed?

There's rendered video in this [article](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/martian-rover-zhurong-takes-first-drive-surface-red-planet-china-n1268235) that shows some things unfolding, but it skips the ramp deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A longer version of the animation provided by the China National Space Administration and released by China Central Television, can be seen here, starting at 0:32.

It appears that the ramp was stored under the wheels in transit, with both ends folded upwards, and it unfolded, slid out from under the wheels, and was lowered to the Martian Surface.

Comment: Thanks! It looked too long to fit without some kind of folding, that's really what prompted the question, and this shows the folding.